# RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

**I am writing code for my news project in flutter.I have copied this code from one tutorial. But I got exceptions and errors in my code. Anybody please help me to solve the issues. My code is**:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(97),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                        width: 0.5,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ))),
                  child: AppBar(
                    title: Text(
                      'News',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // height: 100,
                )
              ]),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return _listItem(index);
          },
          itemCount: _newsInApp.length,
        ));
  }
```

My console output is:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           22.9s
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro Max...
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
flutter: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you are using that method? @Swift Guy

Comment: @ Timilehin Jegede okie done

Comment: You should remove the `Expanded` widget in the `_listItem` method, `Expanded` widgets don't work inside `Scrollable` widgets. @Swift Guy

Comment: @Timilehin Jegede If I remove Expanded widget then it shows error as "Undefined named 'child'".

Comment: Can you add the code snippet of where you took out the `Expanded` widget?

Comment: child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
          //"Here"       // Expanded( 
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                    child: Text(_newsInApp[index].title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16)

Comment: Too hard to read, add it as a formatted code snippet to your question @Swift Guy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217932/discussion-between-timilehin-jegede-and-swift-guy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `listItem` widget method with :

```
_listItem(index) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 1, right: 1, bottom: 1),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
            child: Text(
              _newsInApp[index].title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          iconSize: 16,
          color: Colors.black26,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```